# Why is the enumeration WebExceptionStatus not intended to be used directly in my code?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest, msdn

The [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) documenting the enumeration `WebExceptionStatus` says:

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.

Why? It is **public** and **documented** and an obvious way to determine why the webrequest failed.

**Example**:

I am using the class `WebRequest` get data from a webserver. Of course, I'll have to do exception handling if an error occurs during the request. So if something goes wrong, I want to seperate protocol errors (example: server returned a response with http status `400`) from network errors (example: timout). For that I wanted the property `Status`:

```
try {
  var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(QueryUri);
  //...
}
catch (WebException exception) {
  if (exception.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
    throw new MyCustomServerErrorException(...)
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I would ignore the documentation warning and consider it misleading. Microsoft is using it in the [Handling Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es54hw8e(v=vs.110).aspx) example.

Comment: the enumeration values of `WebExceptionStatus` are interesting too: which situation may cause status value "Success" - "No error was encountered" ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `((HttpWebResponse)exception.Response).StatusCode`

Comment: @Eser I know that property. But you gave me an idea: instead of checking for a `exception.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`, I could simply check if the `Response` property is not `null` - now I can avoid using the enumeration

Comment: MS is a convicted monopolist. As part of their consent decree with DOJ they agreed to document various APIs and protocols. And now they don't want to run afoul of US and European antitrust laws. That's my guess as to why you see that message sometimes. My opinion: an API documented like that would give MS more justification for removing it in the future, but they obsolete APIs all the time that aren't marked like that, so no guarantees. Note that some MS certification/logo programs (like WHQL) disallow use of certain APIs. If you're working on something you want certified/logoed, consider that